# How to use sum function in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml file with following contents:

```
<Xavor>
<Dev>
    <Emp>1</Emp>
    <Floor>1</Floor>
    <Salary>1200.4</Salary>
</Dev>
<Dev>
    <Emp>2</Emp>
    <Salary>3100.8</Salary>
</Dev>
<Dev>
    <Emp>3</Emp>
    <Floor>1</Floor>
</Dev>
```

I want to calculate sum of salaries of first two Employees using sum function. I came to this XPath:

```
sum(/Xavor/Dev[2]/Salary/text())
```

But this returns only second salary value ie `3100.8`!!!
This XPath was working fine when there were only non-floating point numbers were in salaries. Please help me out.

Comment: If you think this XPath was doing what you ask before, you were mistaken. It clearly selects only the second Dev element, rather than selecting the first two.

Comment: It was working fine BUT with only Non-Floating point numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(/Xavor/Dev[position() &lt;= 2]/Salary/text())
```

Comment: You do need to sum just first two elements, or all elements with `Salary` information?

Comment: If you're testing the XPath expression in Altova XMLSpy, you don't need to change markup into character references. Of course, if you're doing this in XSLT or Stylevision or whatever, that would be necessary. Also, are the employees always going to be in order or do you need to order by `Emp` elements? I've tried it like this, with success: `sum(/*/Dev[Emp <= 2 and Salary]/Salary)`

Comment: G_H thanks for your detailed response. I apologize that i am beginner of XPath so this new XPath is difficult for me understand at this time. It is working with correct output. thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

**In addition to the correct answer by @Rubens Farias, if you want to sum the salaries of all `Dev` that have (numeric) salaries specified, use:**

```
sum(/*/Dev/Salary[number(.) = number(.)])
```

Comment: +1 - I like this approach much better than the 'NaN' approach I usually use. (`sum(/*/Dev/Salary[string(number(.)) != 'NaN'])`)

Comment: @dimitre: Could you explain me (or point some url) how does the [number(.) = number(.)] works. I'd expect it, if found a NaN to also match. Thanks

Comment: @dimitre: I think i got it. NaN = NaN is is never true and hence number(.) = number(.) works when the node is convertible to a number.

Comment: @LuisFilipe, Exactly. By definition NaN is not equal to anything else, including NaN